# Counting all items of an (ImmutableJS) Map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, immutability, immutable.js

Counting the items contained in an object, I used to have:

```
Object.keys(state.posts).length
```

Now, I have changed my `posts` state into an immutablejs Map, like so:

```
Map({ "1": {title: "First Title"}, "2" : {title: "Second Title"} });
```

...but now I don't know how to count the items in the object anymore? I tried a few things like `Object.keys(state.posts.get()).length` and `Object.keys(state.posts.entries()).length`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the size or length of ImmutableJS Map you can do:

```
state.posts.size
```

This is as documented on ImmutableJS [Map#size](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/size)

Comment: thank you this works! I couldnt find it anywhere, maybe I looked for the wrong term! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

According to docs:

`state.posts.count()`

will always return proper size.